# Custom plugin does not apply on dynamic generated select

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, bootstrap-select

I am using [Bootstrap select](https://github.com/heimrichhannot/bootstrap-select)  in my project but there is a problem and it is that in my form user can generate new elements such as `<select>` and so on.

when use add new select and choose on of its items it does not shown as a selected item in select.

Note : It works correctly for static `select` tags in my form.

I generate new elements like this :

```
$(".newrow").on('click', function () {

    debugger;
    var index = (new Date()).getTime(); // unique indexer
    var baseTable = $(this).closest(".added").siblings(".table")
    var clone = $(baseTable).find(".template").clone();
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
    $(baseTable).find("tbody tr:last").after('<tr>' + clone.html() + '</tr>');
});
```

and my template is like this :

```
   <tr class="template"> </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group level3">
                        <select class="selectpicker  form-control" data-live-search="true"  name="Education[#].EducationCenterId">
                            <option value="0">choose an item</option>
                            <option>some other options here </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td></tr>
```

Comment: Also include code in `.template`

Comment: @AswinKumar updated. it was missing.

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/59r2wLyc/7/

Comment: @Vel it does not work . I can not choose any item

Comment: please check now https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/59r2wLyc/8/. you need to inlcude boostrap js and css

Answer (score 1):

Include boostrap.js and css.

**Html**

```
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="template"> 
            <td>
                <div class="form-group level3">
                <select class="selectpicker  form-control" data-live-search="true"  name="Education[#].EducationCenterId">
                    <option value="0">choose an item</option>
                    <option value="test">some other options here </option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
            </table>
             <button class="newrow" value="New row">New</button>

             </button>
```

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".newrow").on('click', function () {
        var index = (new Date()).getTime(); // unique indexer
        var baseTable = $(".table")
        var clone = $(baseTable).find(".template select").clone();
        $(baseTable).find("tbody tr:last").after('<tr><td><select class="selectpicker  form-control" data-live-search="true"  name="Education[#].EducationCenterId">' + clone.html() + '</select></td></tr>');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

[Working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/59r2wLyc/20/)

Comment: Have you tried it ? First add one new select then try to select different item. all of them  has one item and you can not change it

Comment: Answer updated. You didnt add value to select options.

Comment: It has not changed yet. I can only one item for all of them.all option items have value

Comment: you need to destroy multiselect before clone

Comment: This one works. but what do you mean by destroy? where did you destroy multiselect?

Comment: I didnt destroy. I did this on another way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195395/discussion-between-programmer-and-vel).